# Создание последовательности с опцией NOPARTITION, ошибка: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Установлена версия 12.2.0.1.0.

Есть скрипт, который создает последовательность, которую нужно повторно использовать для различных объектов (переименовывая имя последовательности):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE NAME_SEQ MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999
    INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 100 CACHE 200 NOORDER NOCYCLE NOPARTITION;
```

Этот скрипт не работает, выдаёт ошибку:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Но если удалить `NOPARTITION`, то всё работает.

В топике на [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9523071800346490539) говорится, что NOPARTITION не поддерживается в 12.2

> there's been various of things in previous versions of the database that are no longer relevant/supported
> в предыдущих версиях были различные функции, которые больше не актуальны/не поддерживаются.

Почему эта функция не поддерживается и/или чем она заменена?

Если замены нет, то почему эта функция не должна использоваться?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle 12.2 - Replacement of NOPARTITION feature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52731498) от участника [@user7294900](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7294900/user7294900)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/52731498

Answer (score 2):

Опция `(NO)PARTITION n` для последовательностей была введена 12.1 но *никогда* не была документирована, поэтому *никогда* не поддерживалась. В указанной в вопросе статье на *AskTom*, [есть ссылка](https://blog.dbi-services.com/oracle-partitioned-sequences-a-future-new-feature-in-12c), по которой можно узнать подробней об этой опции.

Также в версии 12.1, пакет `DBMS_METADATA` генерировал скрипты для создания таблиц, где ошибочно была указана опция `NOPARTITION` для последовательностей. В 12.2 эта ошибка была устранена.

Во всех скриптах, созданных в версии 12.1 пакетом `DBMS_METADATA`, опция `NOPARTITION` должна быть удалена.

Когда появится эта опция, если вообще появится, нет официальной иформации. В [документации к актуальной версии 21c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-E9C78A8C-615A-4757-B2A8-5E6EFB130571) она отсутствует.

---

> Если замены нет, то почему эта функция не должна использоваться?

Все недокументированные возможности, функции, опции и т.д., могут изменяться без предупреждения, и как раз этот случай - няглядный пример. Их использование строго на свой страх и риск. В этом случае,  изготовитель не несёт никакой ответственности.